# list of all C++ keywords supported by gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, keyword

gcc have their own specific keywords like `__attribute__` which are not part of C++ standard and they dont show up in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

msvs has Microsoft-specific C++ keywords which are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/keywords-cpp?view=msvc-170#microsoft-specific-c-keywords

Where can I find such list for gcc/g++ ?

I'm not familiar with gcc's source code so I will appreciate if I can get link to source code where all these extra keywords supported by gcc are listed

Comment: GCC have very good online documentation, which should be rather easy to find through your favorite search engine. What have you tried searching for? What have you found? How didn't it help you?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Keyword-Index.html

Comment: [Extensions to the C++ Language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions) might be what you want.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I did found that page. a quick Ctrl+F with search `__attribute__` does not give any results and yet I know `__attribute__` is keyowrd supported by gcc

Comment: Do you want to get differences b/w gcc/g++ keyword set?

Comment: @gkhanacer I'm trying to write parser which can parse all C++ functions including the one which uses extensions from msvc and gcc. to create robust parser and take care about corner cases, I need list of all valid keywords

Answer (score 1):

There are many **C/C++ extensions** (non standard) supported by GCC. Find all of them in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html#Top

Regarding to the `__attribute__`, there are also many kinds. E.g. [C function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes), Variable Attributes, Type ..., etc.